# QGroundControl / Qt Project Error: Unsupported Qt version, 5.11+ is required

Tags: c++, qt, qt6, qgroundcontrol

I want to customize QGroundControl (QGC) ground control station for a project I'm working. I have pulled the latest stable release (Branch Stable_V4.2) from git and I am currently stuck in the process of running QGC from source code.

I have followed: QT -> File -> Open File or Project -> "qgroundcontrol.pro" and chose "Desktop Qt 6.4.2 MSVC2019 64bit" kit but as soon as the project opens I get an error named ":-1: error: Project ERROR: Unsupported Qt version, 5.11+ is required".

I checked Help -> System Information page and saw the following output:

- Qt Creator 9.0.1
- Based on Qt 6.4.0 (MSVC 2019, x86_64)
- From revision 938231cf0d
- Built on Dec 14 2022 02:22:23

If I understand correctly, I installed QT using the online installer and it says it has the QT version 6.4.0. I can't figure out wht it says version 5.11+ is required when the condition is seemingly met.

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: QGroundControl needs Qt5, not Qt6

Comment: Thank you chehrlic, installing Qt5 solved the issue. I've just recently started to learn Qt and QGC so I greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As chehrlic pointed out,

> QGroundControl needs Qt5, not Qt6

Therefore installing and using Qt5 solved the problem.